# Profile picture on friends newsfeed

Tags: facebook

How can I make it so that when I change my Facebook profile picture, it won't appear on my friends newsfeed, but could still view it if they went to my profile.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct option to do this. But there are some way.

Hide the post from your timeline immediately.

Click on **View Activity Log** from you profile (a tab on cover photo) and hide the post from your timeline by clicking pencil symbol.

Other thing what I can thing is when you are adding a new profile picture select audience as **Only Me** and after few hours you can change the audience. It will not show the change in friend's newsfeed.